# What are the laws involved with residency requirements when it comes to purchasing real estate in Shanghai?

Tags: real-estate, law, china

Please quote some examples from the laws imposed by the Chinese government, whether it's in English or Chinese (assuming there are a fair number of chinese readers here).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What type of real estate? An apartment? Who owns it? Chinese national, foreigner, etc?

Comment: Apartment. Foreigner.

Answer (score 3):

Foreign real estate investors need to make their investments in Chinese real estate through a company having its corporate seat in China, such company then being registered as owner of the acquired property rights in the Chinese land and property register system ("China PropCo"). The China PropCo usually has the legal form of a limited liability company under Chinese laws and is structured either as a Wholly Foreign-owned Enterprise ("WFOE") or a Joint Venture Company ("JV"). A WFOE is an enterprise in which the equity is held completely by one or more foreign investors. A JV is an association of two or more investors jointly undertaking a commercial enterprise with at least one Chinese investor as partner.

More Details at:
http://www.sjberwin.com/Contents/Publications/pdf/242/187c5448_9592_436f_8d15_02053f70ecef.pdf